# Castle Windsor LifestylePerWcfOperation when working with async\await

Tags: c#, async-await, castle-windsor

I'm building a WCF service using Castle Windsor as my DI container.
I also configured DbContext (called MyAppEntities) to be LifestylePerWcfOperation.
The problem starts when I tried to add

```
[OperationContract]
Task<string> ExecuteAsync(string request);
```

I implemented it like that:

```
public async Task<string> ExecuteAsync(string request)
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => [some work is done 
    here...]);
}
```

what happened is that the work inside the task tried to resolve one of the repositories and get the next exception:

> Could not obtain scope for component MyAppEntities. 
>   This is most likely either a bug in custom IScopeAccessor or you're trying to access scoped component outside of the scope (like a per-web-request component outside of web request etc)
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Could not obtain scope for component MyAppEntities. 
>   This is most likely either a bug in custom IScopeAccessor or you're trying to access scoped component outside of the scope (like a per-web-request component outside of web request etc) (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentResolutionException: Could not obtain scope for component MyAppEntities. This is most likely either a bug in custom IScopeAccessor or you're trying to access scoped component outside of the scope (like a per-web-request component outside of web request etc)
>      at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.GetScope(CreationContext context)
>      at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy)
>      at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden)
>      at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
>      at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context)
>      at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolv...).